# removing an Attribute inside an input field

Tags: javascript, input, attributes, field

I want to remove this attribute

```
class="validate[custom[card]] text-input"
```

on my input field named "card" when the radio containing the value "CreditCard" is unselected. This is the script for my radio box:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[name$='sel']").click(function() {
        var test = $(this).val();

        $("div.desc").hide();
        $("#sel" + test).show();
    });
});
</script>
```

and the input field

```
<table><tr><td>

<p> Credit/Debit Card<lable  style="margin-right:1px;"></lable><input
type="radio" name="sel" id="sel"  value="CreditCard"
class="validate[required] radio-input" /> </p> 


<p> Paypal<input type="radio" id="sel"  name="sel" value="Paypal"   />
</p>


<p> Wire Transfer<input type="radio" id="sel"  name="sel"
value="WireTransfer"  /> </p>

<!====================================================================================> 
</td<td>

<!====================================================================================> 
<div id="selCreditCard" class="desc"> <label for="card"><strong>Card
Number<font color=red size=3> *</font></strong></label>
        <input name="card"   type="text"  id="card" value=""  style="width:85px;" class="validate[custom[card]] text-input" />
</div>
<!====================================================================================> 
<div id="selPaypal" class="desc" style="display:
none;margin-left:20px;margin-top:1px;margin-bottom:1px;"> paypal
</div>
<!====================================================================================> 
<div id="selWireTransfer" class="desc" style="display:
none;margin-left:20px;margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:-5px;"> wired
</div>
<!====================================================================================>
</td></tr></table>
```

and when the user unselects the radio, the attribute will be returned.

Comment: Please create a http://jsfiddle.net for that to provide a good playground for people wanting to help you.

Comment: have you considered using data- attributes for your validation instead of validate[required] as a class? `data-validate="required"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are using jQuery. You want to remove the class attribute.

In jquery there is the `removeClass()` method.

So, you would do:

```
$("input[name$='sel']").removeClass("validate text-input");
```

**Note:** **validate[custom[card]]** is quite a strange name for a class. I suspect it is not a valid name for a class.

Comment: its  for my regex code and that's a correct code the problem is i can't remove it

Comment: Try to use removeClass() method as I stated.

Answer (score 0):

To remove an attribute with jQuery you can use the `removeAttr(attrName)` method.
To remove a specific class you can use `removeClass(className)`

Posted jquery example because it appears you are using jquery.

```
$("#input").removeAttr("class") // removes the entire attr (all classes/values)
$("#input").removeClass("myClass") // removes just the class called myClass
```

Comment: i've removed the attrbute the problem iss i can't get it back

Comment: Once its removed its gone. You can use `addClass('classname')` to add classes to an attribute or `.attr('class', 'className')`. If you want to save a reference to the attribute before you remove it you can do that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will work:

```
    var radio_select="";
        $(document).ready(function() {
        if(radio_select!="")
        {
        previous_radio_select_id=radio_select_id;
        if(radio_select=="CreditCard")
        {
        $('.validate[custom[card]] .text-input').removeClass('validate[custom[card]] text-input');
        }
        }
        radio_select=$('form input[type=radio]:checked').val();
radio_select_id=$('form input[type=radio]:checked').attr('id');
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

ok solved my problem

i used

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[name$='sel']").click(function() {
        var test = $(this).val();

        $("div.desc").hide();
        $("#sel" + test).show();

     if(test != "CreditCard"){
         $("#card").prop('class','')
         }
     else{
              $("#card").prop('class','validate[custom[card]] text-input')
     }  
    });
});
</script>
```